# Вывод изображения на весь экран со скрытием часов, батареи и т.п

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Сделал просмотр галереи на весь экран. Для ПК браузеров изображение показывает как надо, скрыты все горизонтальные панели Windows и браузера, если установить браузер в режим на весь экран. Для мобильного же просмотра, например, Андроид остаётся горизонтальное меню где находятся часы, батареи и т.п.

Есть ли способ скрыть данное горизонтальное блок Андроид при просмотреть в браузере в полноэкранном режиме и какие?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966923/fullscreen-via-javascript-on-chrome-for-android-tablets
Как говорят в таких случаях - `Вас что в гугле забанили?` :)

Comment: Если впервые столкнуться, то и google не сразу может помочь в этом, искал несколько дней.  П.С. Нашёл вот такое решение https://github.com/MSchmidt/jquery-fullsizable